# get multiple data from column in one row

Tags: mysql

In the column tutor, tutors can be duplicated but project numbers are unique. I need to get all tutors and all the project numbers they have.

for example I have:

```
column tutor                column projects
Steve                         1
Theo                          2
John                          3
Steve                         4
```

And the result I need is:

```
Steve 1, 4
Theo 2
John 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT tutor, GROUP_CONCAT(projects SEPARATOR ',') AS projects_list
FROM your_table
GROUP BY tutor
```

Documentation: [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: @tombom: According to the documentation link I posted, the default separator between values in a group is comma. Then it is useless to explicitely specify it in `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Good to know. Anyway, you got the +1 from me and it doesn't hurt either.